# Angular2 Router "overwrites" templates

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I implemented routing to my app, but it doesn't work as intended. When I click Login button it should navigate to a new login-page, but instead, it creates a login-page inside main page(`VehicleComponent`). Here's the code:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { VehicleComponent } from './vehicle.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: '', redirectTo: '/vehicle', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'vehicle', component: VehicleComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Part of **VehicleComponent.ts**

```
  toLogin(): void {
    console.log("toLogin button");
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
```

**Template**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="toLogin()">Login</button>
```

**LoginComponent**

```
onSubmit(): void { 
    console.log("Submit button");
}
goBack(): void {
    console.log("Back button");
    this.location.back();
}
```

[image: VehicleComponent]

[image: After clicking Login]
 Button "Back" on LoginComponent works fine, just "Login" on VehicleComponent is broken. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/login']);`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you see if you visit http://yoursite/login by typing the URL directly?

Comment: `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.`

Comment: @anshuVersatile If this might be useful, in order to use my app on the server I had to set href on index.html: `<base href="/test/">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. I added another compomnent, just to be a placeholder for `<router-link></router-link>`, then uncommented `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/vehicle', pathMatch: 'full' }` in my **app-routing.module**. Now it works as intended.